# How to completely remove eslint from project

Tags: npm, eslint

I would like to get rid of Eslint on my project, but I can't figure out how. My `package.json` does *not* have any mention of eslint inside:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "firebase": "^9.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "plaid": "^10.3.0",
    "uniqid": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
```

There are *no* eslint files inside my project, and my global npm installs does *not* contain eslint.

```
$ npm list -g
C:\Users\sales\AppData\Roaming\npm
├── nodemon@2.0.14
├── npm@8.9.0
└── yarn@1.22.17
```

What else should I do so eslint is not on my project?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete .eslintrc and any other eslint config files, if any, from the project.

Also, check your `package.json` and delete all eslint packages and do `npm install` on your project.

If you are using vscode, you can disable it with a [simple setting](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/123#issuecomment-243613973).

Comment: Hey, I stated in my question I don't have it inside my package.json or any eslint files in my project directory, and I checked out that link you provided and it still didn't work. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).